# Unhandled Promise rejection warning in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting an unhandled Promise rejection warning. I am working with pupetteer to navigate a webpage. The code runs perfectly but i think there is poor error handling

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const LOGIN_PG = 'https://website.com'

puppeteer.launch({headless: false}, {defaultViewport: null}).then(async browser => {
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  const navigationPromise = page.waitForNavigation()
  await page.goto(LOGIN_PG, {waitUntil: "networkidle2"})
  await page.focus('input[id=loginform-login]')
  await page.keyboard.type('username')
  await page.focus('input[id=loginform-password]')
  await page.keyboard.type(password)
  await page.click('button[type=submit]')  

 for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
  await navigationPromise

  try {
  await page.waitForSelector('a[class]',{timeout: 60000})
  await page.click('a[class]',{timeout: 60000})
      }
      catch (e){
      console.log (e)
      if (TimeoutError == false){
        break
      }
      }
console.log('check number ' + i)
while (i == 10 || i == 20) {

console.log('refresh')
await page.reload({waitUntil: "load"})
    break
  }
}
console.log('object found')
await page.waitForSelector('input[class]')
await page.click('input[class]')
});
```

Comment: The last bit try {
  await page.waitForSelector('a[class]',{timeout: 60000})
  await page.click('a[class]',{timeout: 60000})
      }
      catch (e){
      console.log (e)
      if (TimeoutError == false){
        break
      }
      }
console.log('check number ' + i)
while (i == 10 || i == 20) {

console.log('refresh')
await page.reload({waitUntil: "load"})
    break
  }
}
console.log('object found')
await page.waitForSelector('input[class]')
await page.click('input[class]')
});

Comment: Add all code from `async browser => {` to try catch block also add `.catch(error=>{})` at the end.